# accessing file system on rooted device android

Tags: android

I have made a simple app to populate recycler view with video or audio files. The recycler view get populated when installing app on any android device through android studio but I have a mobile device which is rooted. On this device, no audio or video file is detected nor recycler view get populated. Any solution for this problem please?

@Klox

```
private var videosPaths:ArrayList<File> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var pathsViewModel: PathsViewModel
private val videoFormat = arrayOf(".mp4", ".MP4", ".mkv", ".MKV")

// here I'm inserting video/audio files in database created
// room database files are not shown here

val pathsDao = PathsDatabase.getPathsInstance(applicationContext).pathsDao()
val pathsRepository = PathsRepository(pathsDao)
val pathsMainDatabase = PathsMainDatabase()
pathsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, PathsViewModelFactory(pathsRepository))[PathsViewModel::class.java]

// I have created database with name "video_paths"
if(!applicationContext.getDatabasePath("videos_paths").exists()) {
            videosPaths = getVideoFolders()

// here videoPaths returns 0 video folders on rooted device and as app
// opens, it gives toast message: "shell granted superuser access"

            videosPaths.forEach{ file ->
                pathsViewModel.insertPath(Paths(0, file.absolutePath))
            }
        }

// my custom code for extracting video/audio files in device w/o using cursor library

//getting video folders

fun getVideoFolders() : ArrayList<File> {
    searchVideoFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
        return videoFolders
    }


// a recursive function to scan video files in device all folders
private fun searchVideoFiles(file: File) {
        val dir = file.listFiles() ?: return
        for (f in dir) {
            if (f.isDirectory) {
                searchVideoFiles(f)
                if (isVideoFolder(f)) videoFolders.add(f)
            }
        }
    }


// return true if at least one video file is found
private fun isVideoFolder(file: File?): Boolean {
        assert(file != null)
        assert(file!!.isDirectory)
        val dir = file.listFiles() ?: return false
        for (f in dir) {
            val path = f.absolutePath
            for(v in videoFormat) {
                if(path.endsWith(v)) return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Yes, can happen. I have no audio and video files too.

Comment: Please share the code that is trying to detect files, and explain what that code is detecting instead (no files? errors? some files but not the ones you want?).